# Unguessable integer primary keys for MySQL

Tags: mysql, guid, uuid

I'm working on a database that uses integers as primary keys for a number of tables. I'd like to make the primary keys relatively difficult to guess — they needn't be super-tight, just not incrementing integers in the low hundreds. Since I'm retrofitting this into existing schemata, with existing data, changing the datatype of the primary key (`integer`) is not feasible. What I'm wondering is how best to generate the IDs. So far, I can think of these options:

1. Generate UUIDs using `UUID()` and convert them to integer.
2. Keep a separate table full of random integers and use a procedure to select and delete one from the table inside a transaction.
3. Use the UNIX timestamp, plus a random, n-digit number, e.g. `CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),SUBSTRING(RAND() FROM 3 FOR 6))`

I'm open to other suggestions, too.

I'd appreciate any thoughts you can offer.

Thanks,
Ross

Comment: Why do you need to so this? Doesn't your application enforce any greater security than relying on people not guessing valid IDs?

Comment: related: guids are frequently partially sequential to allow best performance (`newsequentialid()` on SQL 2005+), enable use of clustered indexes and database replication, IIRC. See, e.g. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html

Comment: @MartinSmith: this kind of information leakage is more frequently a concern to privacy than security. But the information leaked could be used for strategic advantage (e.g. knowing exactly how many items a webshop sold today, or how many complaints have been filed with a company etc.)

Comment: @sehe - Good point on your edit.

Comment: @MartinSmith: exactly my point. I was insisting that it should be a concern because of other things than security. Even if you have 'any greater security' you still want to be able to prevent leaking info. You can try to 'solve' this by requiring all programmers to adhere to a coding policy to replace database ID's by _salted_ cryptographic hashes for use in JSON results (and all other places). That is a brittle solution and _will_ be forgotten

Comment: Use the uuid() function to have MySQL generate the value: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: @MartinSmith As sehe suggests, we're using these for order IDs and don't want to give away the number of orders placed with an auto-incrementing ID.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you doing that? You'll mess up the way the data is physically stored. Use secondary index and make it a GUID if you need to pass it trough URLs for lookups.

Comment: +1 Your primary key should just be an autoincrement unsigned int - the "hard to guess, will be visible in URL" a second column.